# Matlab Split Text in to sentences

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a text file:

```
The annual festival. Of every man is the fund which originally.

Supplies it with all the necessaries? And conveniences of birth which

it annually forgone! And which consist always either in the immediate

produce of that action, or in what is wasted with that produce from

other nations.
```

I need to split it into sentences. Its a simplistic version but you can assume that all sentences end with one of the following `.` `?` `!` and with a space and capital letter following one of those punctuation.

I tried various ways using function `strsplit` and this is the closes one but its still wrong.

```
strsplit(textfile2,{'. ','! ','? '}) %doesnt work fully

textfil2 = 

'The annual festival'    [1x80 char]    [1x53 char]    [1x133 char]
```

I want my output to be in a string cell array like:

```
The annual festival
Of every man is the fund which originally
Supplies it with all the necessaries
And conveniences of birth which it annually forgone
And which consist always either in the immediate produce of that action, or in what is wasted with that produce from other nations
```

but with no ending periods behind each of them. Any ideas?

Comment: `textfil2` is a cell array of strings. You just want a rectangular character array?

Comment: sorry when i read in 'textfile2', its of class `char`. I want the final output to be a cell array of strings.

Comment: The output of `strsplit` is a cell array of strings. I'm not clear on the issue.

Comment: sorry im new to matlab, but that the output of strsplit from command input `strsplit(textfile2,{'. ','! ','? '})` doesn't split it to the output i want. So say I stored the output in variable `x`, when I do x(1) it should return `The annual festival` and when I do x(2) it should return `Of every man is the fund which originally`. So each cell in the cell array stores a sentence. But in the above, x(2) gives `[1x80 char]`, what happen to the sentence?

Comment: do `x{1}` (curly braces)

Comment: I am getting a sense I got the right answer with my command, but I am interpretting the output incorrectly. But thinking about it, there is suppose to be 5 sentences, but the above yields only 4, assuming `[1x80 char]    [1x53 char]    [1x133 char]` are sentences...

Comment: That's because there's no space after the last sentence.  Search for punctuation without spaces and trim the output, or use regexp as in the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curly braces to access the character arrays in the cell array from `strsplit`:

```
x{1}
```

---

If you want to keep the punctuation at the end of the sentence:

```
sentences = regexp(textarray,'\S.*?[\.\!\?]','match')
```

The right way to split without trailing punctuation, and keep the last sentence:

```
sentences = regexp(text,'[\.\!\?]\s*','split')
```

To quickly check the output: `char(sentences)`.

Comment: this works, but what if I don't want to keep the punctuation at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `regexp` in MATLAB.

```
text='The annual festival. Of every man is the fund which originally. Supplies it with all the necessaries? And conveniences of birth which it annually forgone! And which consist always either in the immediate produce of that action, or in what is wasted with that produce from other nations.' 
SplitString=regexp(text,'[\.?!,]','split')

for it=1:length(SplitString)
display(SplitString(it));
end
```